# How to click a point and save its coordinates in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, geometry

I have a couple of points visualized in a leaflet map as you can see in the figure:

[image]

I would like to add a function that selects as many of these points I want and save their geometry. I have done something similar to show the provider and the battery attributes of the selected markers:

```
function onEachFeature ( feature , layer )
    {
        var popupContent = "Provider: " + feature.properties.provider + '</b><br/>' + "Battery level: " + feature.properties.battery;
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }
```

I would like some guidelines on how to create a click event when I click on the markers and how I can save the geometry (maybe to an array).

I know the question is kinda general but I would really appreciate any help since its my first project using html,javascript and css.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click listener to the marker. In the click listener you can use the unique leaflet id of the marker to add and remove them from the list:

```
var selectedData = {};
function onEachFeature ( feature , layer )
    {
        var popupContent = "Provider: " + feature.properties.provider + '</b><br/>' + "Battery level: " + feature.properties.battery;
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
        layer.on('click',(e)=>{
            var marker = e.target;
            if(selectedData[marker._leaflet_id]){
               delete selectedData[marker._leaflet_id];
            } else {
               selectedData[marker._leaflet_id] = marker;
            }
        })
    }
```

To get all markers in the list use:

```
for(var id in selectedData){
   var marker = selectedData[id];
   console.log(marker.getLatLng())
   console.log(marker.toGeoJSON())
}
```

Comment: Ok perfect. Now I can select a single point and see its attributes in a window. I would like to POST the selectedData to a table to pgadmin. I use this code: // DO POST
  $.ajax (
    {
     type : "POST",
     contentType :"application/json",
     url : "/save_marker",
     data : JSON.stringify(loc_data),
     success: function (marker)
     {
      map.closePopup();
      //load_markers();
     },
     error : function (e) {
      alert ("Error!");
      console.log ("ERROR:",e);
     }
    });
 });
Also, I can use the app.post in my .js. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Your code looks good. Please accept the answer as correct